# Sencha touch scroll issue when tabbing between text fields

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch

I've got a number of text fields on a panel in my Sencha Touch (2.3) app.

When I use the tab key to navigate down through the panel, the scroll position gets updated accordingly.

However, after tabbing down the page, when I try to scroll the panel (either up or down), the panel is behaving as if the scroll position is still at the top and the scrolling gets out of whack. This causes the scrolling to lock or make the panel content go off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by attaching listener that calls the scrollTo function when a control field gets focus. This will ensure that the scroll position is set correctly which normally isn't the case with a tabbing in Sencha Touch.

```
MyApp.utils.Global.attachScrollToOnFocus([
                    'firstTextField',
                    'secondTextField',
                    'thirdTextField'
                ], scroller, container);
```

And the utility method:

```
attachScrollToOnFocus: function(inputs, scroller, container){
    var i, scroll = function(e){
        var pos = -(container.getY() - Ext.get(e.target.id).getY());
        if(pos > scroller.getMaxPosition().y) {
            scroller.scrollToEnd();
        }
        else {
            scroller.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    };
    for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        Ext.get(inputs[i]).on({
            focus: scroll
        });
    }
}
```